# The kit Desktop Qt 5.7.1 MSVC2013 64bit has configuration issues

Tags: qt, boost, qt-creator

I tried the following boost example:
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/regex/example/snippets/captures_example.cpp

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jY3bD.png)

but I got some errors
Compile output:

```
     10:27:26: Running steps for project test_b...
10:27:26: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
10:27:27: Starting: "C:\Qt\Qt5.7.1\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" 
    C:\Qt\Qt5.7.1\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe -f Makefile.Debug
    cl -c -nologo -Zc:wchar_t -FS -Zi -MDd -GR -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -w44996 -EHsc /Fddebug\test_b.vc.pdb -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_CORE_LIB -I..\test_b -I. -IC:\local\boost_1_59_0 -IC:\Qt\Qt5.7.1\5.7\msvc2013_64\include -IC:\Qt\Qt5.7.1\5.7\msvc2013_64\include\QtCore -Idebug -IC:\Qt\Qt5.7.1\5.7\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\win32-msvc2013 -Fodebug\ @C:\Users\Nourhan\AppData\Local\Temp\main.obj.3688.125.jom
main.cpp
..\test_b\main.cpp(22) : error C2039: 'captures' : is not a member of 'boost::match_results<std::_String_const_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char>>>,std::allocator<_Ty>>'
        with
        [
            _Ty=boost::sub_match<std::_String_const_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char>>>>
        ]
..\test_b\main.cpp(22) : error C2228: left of '.size' must have class/struct/union
..\test_b\main.cpp(28) : error C2039: 'captures' : is not a member of 'boost::match_results<std::_String_const_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char>>>,std::allocator<_Ty>>'
        with
        [
            _Ty=boost::sub_match<std::_String_const_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char>>>>
        ]
jom: C:\Users\Nourhan\Documents\qt\Debug\Makefile.Debug [debug\main.obj] Error 2
jom: C:\Users\Nourhan\Documents\qt\Debug\Makefile [debug] Error 2
10:27:33: The process "C:\Qt\Qt5.7.1\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project test_b (kit: Desktop Qt 5.7.1 MSVC2013 64bit)
The kit Desktop Qt 5.7.1 MSVC2013 64bit has configuration issues which might be the root cause for this problem.
When executing step "Make"
10:27:33: Elapsed time: 00:07.
```

I appreciate any help , thanks

Comment: Did you define a function `void print_captures(const std::string& regx, const std::string& text)` as in the example? Your screenshot does not show your entire code so it is hard to guess what's wrong.

Comment: @vonludi https://i.stack.imgur.com/jY3bD.png